# Sliding dominoes to transfer empty cell

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n\geq 3$ be an odd positive integer. An $n\times n$ board is covered by $1\times 2$ dominoes, so that only one cell remains uncovered, and that cell is at a corner. By sliding dominoes on the board, can we always transfer the empty cell to any other corner?

An idea is to think of a graph, with the vertices being the cells with both coordinates odd (hence including all four corners), and two vertices connected by an edge if they're two cells apart and a domino covers the cell in between as well as one of the two cells. If all four corners are connected in this graph, we would be done.